# Is there any way to define multiple style files to avoid a single huge one in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-styles

I would like to know is there any way to define or use multiple styles files(`Multiple, style.xml files`) in `Android`, rather than the single `style.xml` file which is present in the `res` folder of the `Application Project`. As currently I am using a single style file `(style.xml)`. But the size of the `style.xml` file is huge due to my many customized and self-defined styles.

I had gone through many tutorials and examples, But all those tutorial and example providing sites and even the `developer.android.com` site shows how to define and use `Style` but, none of the any site says whether it is possible to Make `Multiple style.xml files` of the single `style.xml` file so that the size of the file can be reduced.

Any Help would be Appreciated...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are welcome to have as many resources defining styles as you like, at least within reason. There's probably some file-count limit, but it's at least in the hundreds, and possibly in the low billions.

In `res/values/`, and `res/values-*/` directories, **filenames do not matter**. We use conventions to put resources in files named after the resource, like `styles.xml`. That is merely an organization system. You are welcome to have as many files with `<style>` resources as you want, named whatever you want (so long as they are valid resource filenames).

For example, in your Android SDK, if you go to `platforms/android-.../data/res/values/` (for some value of `...`, based on your installed SDKs), you will see several files that contain style resources:

- `styles.xml`
- `styles_*.xml`, such as `styles_holo.xml`
- `themes.xml`
- `themes_*.xml`, such as `themes_material.xml`

Comment: Well If I have to Define my EditText Style in one style.xml and TextView Style in other style.xml, For Example. Is it possible? And If Yes, How to achive it? Could you Please eleborate?

Comment: ... and how do you reference these other style sheets ... suppose I have `res/values/styles.xml` and `res/values/styles_02.xml` and `res/values/styles_buttons.xml`

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd: "and how do you reference these other style sheets" -- you don't reference "style sheets". You reference the style resources defined in those files. The filenames in `res/values/` and `res/values-*/` directories do not matter.

Comment: @DaniloDeQueiroz: Not that I am aware of. But usually even a large project only needs a few of these files.

Answer (score 1):

You can have those styles on any file you want, it won't matter as long as your filenames are valid. So. For example you can create a style file just for buttons. Don't worry about the order, the styles on all files will be parsed and applied.

Comment: Well If I have to Define my EditText Style in one style.xml and TextView Style in other style.xml, For Example. Is it possible? And If Yes, How to achive it? What could be the names of my styles.xml files in the case? Could you Please eleborate?